# Get data of foreign key relations in a Serializer Django:Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    task_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey('Project')



class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I am writing a serializer for task

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'id',
            'task_name',
            'task_description',
            'project_id',
                 )
```

But i want the project name as well in the TaskSerializer which can be accessed using the project_id. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a serializer for your `project_id` field, eg you might have a `ProjectSerializer` which is a very basic modelserializer. Use that like so:

```
 class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project_name', )

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project_id = ProjectSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'id',
            'task_name',
            'task_description',
            'project_id')
```

Also might worht noting: when naming foreignkey relation its generally a good practice to just go with the realted model name instead of something different. `project_id` would in this case just become `project`. [source: Working with models in django](http://steelkiwi.com/blog/best-practices-working-django-models-python/)

Comment: This gives me a project_name not defined for Task object error.
I want both ID as well as name in the response!

Comment: Well in this case you get a nested response. Ie you will have to access name via task.project_id.project_name. To add project id in the response just modify the projectserializer